# How to write a yocto recipe for gRPC++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, cross-compiling, yocto, grpc

So i am trying to cross compile gRPC for yocto (target) on a Ubuntu host. The recipe located here https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/meta-iot-cloud/tree/master/recipes-support/grpc is only for C and Python but not C++.

Can I get some help on writing a yocto recipe for cross-compiling gRPC++ as well? Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just compile with C through yocto and use as a library as intended by the provided recipe?

Comment: @mascoj Hi Mascoj. The problem is my programs depends on grpc++. To cross compile my program I have to cross compile gRPC++ first so that bitbake can find all gRPC++ dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, I misread and didn't see you meant gRPC++ and not gRPC. gRPC++ comes with a Makefile so you should be able to create a recipe that pulls from github and runs make.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've specific problems you just need to write another recipe.  Use recipetool to create a starting point for the recipe and edit it as required.